# fatal error: call to undefined function redirect()

Tags: php, redirect

I am using [mobiledetect](http://mobiledetect.net/) for redirect mobile users to a specific page. But, when I'm writing this then I am getting the Fatal error for `redirect()`. Can anyone please let me know where and what I'm missing?

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
$deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');
$scriptVersion = $detect->getScriptVersion();

if ($detect->isMobile())
   redirect('iammobile.php');
else
   echo '<h1>I am Desktop</h1>';
```

Comment: `redirect()` is not a function. Error is fairly clear. Where are you creating this function? Do you actually want the [`header()`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function?

Comment: See this question for a lot of options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: That means it couldn't find a function with a name `redirect` anywhere. Try using `header("Location:iammobile.php")` instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `header` like

```
header("Location: iammobile.php");
die();
```

Comment: Hi,
When I used like this:

        `if ($detect->isMobile())`
        `header("Location: iammobile.php");`

Then it shows Internal Server Error

Comment: You need to give entire url of that file..while redirecting

Comment: You meant Like this: `home/user/public_html/` ?

Comment: Still didn't work. I tried with `/home3/chew/public_html/fundmanagementsystem.com/demo/mobile/mobile.php`

and

`http://google.com` too

Comment: Check your server logs to see why it's showing internal server error

Answer (score 2):

Use This function as construct

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

Use this code as redirect

```
redirect(base_url().'login','refresh');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 redirect('iammobile.php');
```

replace it with

```
  header('location:iammobile.php');
```

Comment: Hi,
When I used like this:

        `if ($detect->isMobile())`
        `header("Location: iammobile.php");`

Then it shows Internal Server Error

Comment: are you check this condition on `iammobile.php` if yes it will redirects in looping.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than redirect you should use the `header` function:

```
<?php
    header("Location: iammobile.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');` in file autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

Add construct function in your constructor then your redirect function will work.

`function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}`